# Nodejs: What does `process.binding` mean?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, v8, undocumented-behavior

I've seen `process.binding('...')` many times while researching through the [node.js source code on github](https://github.com/nodejs/node).

Can anybody explain me what this function does?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This function returns internal module, like require. It's not public, so you shouldn't rely on it in your code, but you can use it to play with node's low level objects, if you want to understand how things work.

For example, [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/19ffb5cf1c50e9d91d0a7a35152d20f175a2385d/src/timer_wrap.cc#L148) `timer_wrap` binding is registered. It [exports](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/19ffb5cf1c50e9d91d0a7a35152d20f175a2385d/src/timer_wrap.cc#L50) `Timer` constructor. In `lib/timers.js` it's [imported](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/19ffb5cf1c50e9d91d0a7a35152d20f175a2385d/lib/timers.js#L3)

Comment: `process.binding` seems to change to `internalBinding` from v11.x

Answer (score 21):

It's a feature that essentially goes out and grab the C++ feature and make it available inside the javascript .
Take this example `process.binding('zlib')` that is used in [zlib](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/zlib.js)

This is essentially going out and getting the zlib C++ object and then it's being used the rest of the time in the javascript code.

So when you use zlib you're not actually going out
and grabbing the C++ library, you're using the Javascript library that wraps the C++ feature for you.

It makes it easier to use

Comment: Thanks for the brief and crisp explanation.

Answer (score 8):

process.binding connects the javascript side of Node.js to the C++ side of the Node.js. C++ side of node.js is where a lot of the internal work of everything that node does, is actually implemented. So a lot of your code relies upon ultimately C++ code. Node.js is using the power of C++.

Here is an example:

```
const crypto=require(“crypto”)
const start=Date.now()
crypto.pbkdf2(“a”, “b”, 100000,512,sha512,()=>{
console.log(“1”:Date.now()-start)
})
```

Crypto is a built-in module in Node.js for hashing and saving passwords. This is how we implement it in Node.js but actual hashing process takes place in C++ side of node.js.

when node.js runs this function, actually inside of this function, it passes all the arguments to the `PBKDF2()` function which is the c++ code. this function does all the calculations and returns the result. this is how PBKDF imported to the javascript side of the node.js

```
const {PBKDF2}=process.binding(“crypto”)
```

So this is how javascript side of node.js is connected to the c++ side of node.js. in the c++ side of node.js, V8 is going to translate the node.js values into their c++ equivalents.